# Are the two network the same in the implementation of PPO2 in openai baselines/stable baselines

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Looking at the code, I notice that there are a train_model and a act_model. In the PPO2 algorithm, the two networks are different and train_model is the network with updated parameters. Act_model is the one with old parameters and gets synchronized to the train_model from time to time. From the code and the post
[enter link description here](https://github.com/openai/baselines/issues/473), 
it seems that the two network shares the same weights, which shouldn't be the case.
My question is, where do the train_model and act_model update their weights? Where does the act_model get syncrhonized to the trian_model?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: @shtse8 they are actually the same network. The weights get updated during very train_step. Basically in the beginning of each update, you use act_model to a batch of collect experience. Then you enter the training phase, where the weights of train_model(as well as act_model, since they are the same) get updated during each mini-batch/epoch.